# Shopify, return product tags except certain prefixed tags, in Javascript

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

New to Shopify and Liquid (enjoying it). Not greatly experienced with JS! We have Shopify site that uses product tags for the chocolates in various chocolate boxes. The theme is not compatible with *collection filtering* and is setup to use tags for this also. Thus the tags now contain "Price £10 - £20" etc.

I have code on the product page that loops over all product tags and renders a snippet unless the tag contains 'price':

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
  {% unless tag contains 'Price' %}
    <li>{% render 'chocolate-menu' with tag as tag %}</li>
  {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

All good and easy (with StackOverflow help). However, on the collection pages the 'quickview' option (which launches a popup) inserts a list of the chocolates (tags) via javascript:

```
var chocolatesMenu = product.tags;
var chocolatesMenuSpaced = chocolatesMenu.join(', ');
quickview.find(".proBoxInfo .quickViewSKU").append("<label>Chocolates:</label> " + chocolatesMenuSpaced);
```

How can I 'scrub' the price-related tags from `product.tags` in js? Or is there a clever liquid and js way to do this? I just want to list all tags that don't start with 'Price'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that in Javascript you can filter the Price value, as you're doing in liquid.

```
var chocolatesMenu = "{{ product.tags }}".split(",").filter((tag)=> tag.indexOf("Price")<0);
// OR if you somehow have already product.tags in Javascript
// var chocolatesMenu = product.tags.filter((tag)=> tag.indexOf("Price")<0);
var chocolatesMenuSpaced = chocolatesMenu.join(', ');
quickview.find(".proBoxInfo .quickViewSKU").append("<label>Chocolates:</label> " + chocolatesMenuSpaced);
```

But my suggestion is: don't.

What happens if one day, you need one more tag for a different topic? Are you going to modify all the places where you filtered out "Price" and add "newTag"?

You should be using metafields. If you're theme is not compatibile with metafields, maybe find a better one.

In alternative what you can do is using tag prefixes.

So instead of having `white,dark,milk,Price 10` you should have `kind:white,kind:dark,kind:milk,price:Price 10` and you always filter by kind or price or whataver.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! I take your point about the limitations, but the theme is set. I am using metafields elsewhere. I also think this should be able to be accomplished from the product price - all I'm trying to be is give the option to narrow a collection by price range. Are you able to show an example of how the code you suggest can be added to mine above?

Comment: @IAMmw I have edited the answer to make it clear how to use the JS code. I'm not sure if `product.tags` was a typo or you hve that variable in JS. If the second is the case you can skip the `{{ }}`

Comment: Your a legend! Thanks for the help. Second code example works (example containing the liquid tag doesn't for some reason in my case?). The `product.tags` must be a variable in the JS file. It's not a typo. I take your point about scalability and maintainability considerations. In our case the product range in not likely to exceed 100 (and probably much less). The theme has some support for tag prefixes in its tag filtering menu structure. Again, thanks for your help. (let me know where to send the chocolates!)